# Is it possible to adjust the white balance of an image using Paint Shop Pro?

Tags: images, software-recommendation, corel-paint-shop-pro

I use an old software called Paint Shop Pro 5.03. Can I use it to make white balance for photo or scanned images of artworks?

Are there any other freeware software which can accomplish this?

Comment: Most probably it has a levels tool

Comment: @joojaa It hasn't a grey point picker.

Comment: @user287001 does not need to you can still adjust each channel individually can you not. Admittedly been a while since i used it. However might be just better to update to something like kirta or...

Comment: @joojaa the logic is different than in Photoshop. I added an answer about it.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an old piece of software, at least 20 years gone since this was new. Then I knew nothing about it.

But you can do it. A difficult way is to adjust the RGB balance with Color > Adjust > R/G/B. Its difficult because the sliders move too much with the mouse and the job isn't intuitive.

If you want a picker which you use to point a color which should be grey, you need an add-on. Fortunately 32 bit Photoshop plugins work. Only add to the program folder a new folder named Plugins for them.

A good commercial one is ColorWasher https://thepluginsite.com/products/photowiz/colorwasher/index.htm

Free plugins for the job exist. An example (I have used it and it works): http://www.colormancer.com/free/download-filters/white-balance-plug-in.htm

Place the plugin file, for ex. **WhiteBalanceRecovery.8bf** to the Plugins folder and start PSP. The effect is available in Image > Plugin Filters

Comment: Do you mean 'Image > User defined Filters' which I see instead  - 'Image > Plugin Filters'?

Comment: @Vitaly I mean what I wrote. Plugin Filters pops visible when you have inserted at least one plugin.

Comment: Well, the program is still alive. The current version is 2019 so...